# Codeigniter Custom user field using shield

Tags: codeigniter

I'm using the codeigniter shield authorization and login system.
I'm trying, following the official guide, to insert a custom user field.
there is probably some step that wasn't clear to me or that I didn't perform correctly, because when I register a new user, the new custom field is not stored in the user table.

here my code. the custom field name are "cellulare"

I'm sure I'm missing a step, but I can't figure out which one.
Thanks to everyone who will help me understand the problem.

Migration

```
<?php

namespace App\Database\Migrations;

use CodeIgniter\Database\Forge;
use CodeIgniter\Database\Migration;

class AddMobileNumberToUsers extends Migration
{
    /**
     * @var string[]
     */
    private array $tables;

    public function __construct(?Forge $forge = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($forge);

        /** @var \Config\Auth $authConfig */
        $authConfig   = config('Auth');
        $this->tables = $authConfig->tables;
    }

    public function up()
    {
        $fields = [
            'cellulare' => ['type' => 'VARCHAR', 'constraint' => '20', 'null' => true],
        ];
        $this->forge->addColumn($this->tables['users'], $fields);
    }

    public function down()
    {
        $fields = [
            'cellulare',
        ];
        $this->forge->dropColumn($this->tables['users'], $fields);
    }
}
```

UserModel.php

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Shield\Models\UserModel as ShieldUserModel;

class UserModel extends ShieldUserModel
{

    protected function initialize(): void
    {
        parent::initialize();

        $this->allowedFields = [
            ...$this->allowedFields,

            'cellulare',
        ];
    }
}
```

Validation.php

```
<?php

namespace Config;

use CodeIgniter\Config\BaseConfig;
use CodeIgniter\Validation\StrictRules\CreditCardRules;
use CodeIgniter\Validation\StrictRules\FileRules;
use CodeIgniter\Validation\StrictRules\FormatRules;
use CodeIgniter\Validation\StrictRules\Rules;

class Validation extends BaseConfig
{
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Setup
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Stores the classes that contain the
     * rules that are available.
     *
     * @var string[]
     */
    public array $ruleSets = [
        Rules::class,
        FormatRules::class,
        FileRules::class,
        CreditCardRules::class,
    ];

    /**
     * Specifies the views that are used to display the
     * errors.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    public array $templates = [
        'list'   => 'CodeIgniter\Validation\Views\list',
        'single' => 'CodeIgniter\Validation\Views\single',
    ];

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Rules
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    public $registration = [
        'username' => [
            'label' => 'Auth.username',
            'rules' => [
                'required',
                'max_length[30]',
                'min_length[3]',
                'regex_match[/\A[a-zA-Z0-9\.]+\z/]',
                'is_unique[users.username]',
            ],
        ],
        'cellulare' => [
            'label' => 'cellulare',
            'rules' => [
                'max_length[20]',
                'min_length[10]',
                'regex_match[/\A[0-9]+\z/]',
                'is_unique[users.cellulare]',
            ],
        ],
        'email' => [
            'label' => 'Auth.email',
            'rules' => [
                'required',
                'max_length[254]',
                'valid_email',
                'is_unique[auth_identities.secret]',
            ],
        ],
        'password' => [
            'label' => 'Auth.password',
            'rules' => [
                'required',
                'max_byte[72]',
                'strong_password[]',
            ],
            'errors' => [
                'max_byte' => 'Auth.errorPasswordTooLongBytes',
            ]
        ],
        'password_confirm' => [
            'label' => 'Auth.passwordConfirm',
            'rules' => 'required|matches[password]',
        ],
    ];
}
```

Comment: well, that most likely is a mismatch of name attribute in the view file... could you please check/eventually add the relevant part...

Comment: Please include output of `php spark migrate ` and check if migration is already runned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem found!!!
in auth.php i change this:

public string $userProvider = UserModel::class;

to this:

public string $userProvider = \App\Models\UserModel::class;